# How to exclude matching records in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get a list of customers waiting on service and idle agents based on the following tables:

```
Customers Table
|Customers_ID||Customer Name|
|1           ||John         |
|2           ||Sam          |
|3           ||Kuji         |

Agents Table
|AGENT_ID||AGENT Name|
|99      ||Kelly     |
|98      ||Raji      |
|97      ||Mertle    |

Service Table (Customers being served by Agents)
|QUE_ID||AGENT Name||Customer|
|1001  ||Kelly     ||Kuji    |
|1002  ||Raji      ||Sam     |

SELECT Customer.custname 

FROM Customer LEFT JOIN Service ON ( Customer.custname = Service.custname)

UNION 

SELECT Agent.agentname

FROM Agent RIGHT JOIN Service ON ( Agent.agentname = Service.agentname)

WHERE 
(Agent.agentname = service.agentname) IS NULL 

GROUP BY Customer.custname";
```

This is returning all the values in the customer table and not the customers without agents. How can I exclude the records that already have a match?

Comment: What's your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to check for agents and customers that are not yet in `Service` table:

```
SELECT custname
FROM Customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Service s
    WHERE s.custname = c.custname
)

UNION ALL

SELECT agentname
FROM Agent a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Service s
    WHERE s.agentname = a.agentname
)
```

Comment: Thank You Sooo much. I've been at this for almost two days now O_O'. There was another conditional where clause I needed to add (relative to the date of the agent/customer is idle) i.e. "WHERE Service.Date = $today". I figured out that the where clause needed to be duplicated to achieve this additional condition. Coouldn't have done it without your help.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do a full outer join.  While MySQL does not have a `FULL OUTER JOIN` keyword, you can simulate it by taking the union of two left joins.  The left joins in the query below give the number of idle customers and agents.  The critical piece is the `WHERE ... IS NULL` condition, which will match a customer or agent not already assigned.

```
SELECT c.custname
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Service s
    ON c.custname = s.custname
WHERE s.custname IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT a.agentname
FROM Agent a LEFT JOIN Service s
    ON a.agentname = s.agentname
WHERE s.agentname IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

LEFT or RIGHT JOIN will ensure to return all records with none or some columns having NULL values (in the final table).

You can use NOT EXISTS as per the following (that will reduce the number of records, instead of all):

```
SELECT custname
FROM Customer
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT custname
FROM Service
WHERE Customer.custname = Service.custname)

UNION ALL

SELECT agentname
FROM Agent
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT agentname 
FROM Service s 
WHERE s.agentname = a.agentname)
```